# VBA does not work on text changes unless I press enter

Tags: excel, vba

can anyone please help me with this problem

I'm using combo box to narrow option and I would like to link the option made for the decision to hide or unhide some cells using VBA

[image]

The problem is, when the option was changed, the VBA doesn't re-calculate automatically unless I press the enter button

Here's the code I'm using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim iCell As Range: Set iCell = Intersect(Range("D23"), Target)
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If iCell.value = "by Payor" Then
        Rows("29:78").Hidden = True
        Rows("80:135").Hidden = True
        Rows("137:192").Hidden = True
        Rows("194:249").Hidden = True
    ElseIf iCell.value = "by Specialty" Then
        Rows("29:78").Hidden = False
        Rows("80:135").Hidden = False
        Rows("137:192").Hidden = False
        Rows("194:249").Hidden = False
    'Else ' do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you and I really appreciate all suggestion and help :)

Comment: Try `dropdown_change` event.

Comment: Hi my current problem is the VBA not functioning if the enter button on the linked cell is not pressed, do you have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The code I'm using below is solving my problem. Thanks to Mike, I was able to combine the code and found what I need.

By using this code, when the trigger value changed, the hide/unhide feature is working + the undo changes can also be done.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim iCell As Range
    Set iCell = Range("H23")
    Dim byPayorHidden As Boolean
    Dim bySpecialtyHidden As Boolean

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    byPayorHidden = Rows("29:78").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("86:135").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("143:192").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("200:249").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("264:313").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("321:370").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("378:427").Hidden
    byPayorHidden = Rows("435:484").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("80:85").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("137:142").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("194:199").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("251:251").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("315:320").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("372:377").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("429:434").Hidden
    bySpecialtyHidden = Rows("486:486").Hidden

    If iCell.value = "by Payor" Then
        If Not byPayorHidden Then
            Rows("29:78").Hidden = True
            Rows("85:135").Hidden = True
            Rows("143:192").Hidden = True
            Rows("200:249").Hidden = True
            Rows("264:313").Hidden = True
            Rows("321:370").Hidden = True
            Rows("378:427").Hidden = True
            Rows("435:484").Hidden = True
            byPayorHidden = True
        End If
        If Not bySpecialtyHidden Then
            Rows("80:85").Hidden = True
            Rows("137:142").Hidden = True
            Rows("194:199").Hidden = True
            Rows("251:251").Hidden = True
            Rows("315:320").Hidden = True
            Rows("372:377").Hidden = True
            Rows("429:434").Hidden = True
            Rows("486:486").Hidden = True
            bySpecialtyHidden = True
        End If
    ElseIf iCell.value = "by Specialty" Then
        If byPayorHidden Then
            Rows("29:78").Hidden = False
            Rows("85:135").Hidden = False
            Rows("143:192").Hidden = False
            Rows("200:249").Hidden = False
            Rows("264:313").Hidden = False
            Rows("321:370").Hidden = False
            Rows("378:427").Hidden = False
            Rows("435:484").Hidden = False
            byPayorHidden = False
        End If
        If bySpecialtyHidden Then
            Rows("80:85").Hidden = False
            Rows("137:142").Hidden = False
            Rows("194:199").Hidden = False
            Rows("251:251").Hidden = False
            Rows("315:320").Hidden = False
            Rows("372:377").Hidden = False
            Rows("429:434").Hidden = False
            Rows("486:486").Hidden = False
            bySpecialtyHidden = False
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try next **tested** code:

```
Option Explicit

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065180/vba-does-not-work-on-text-changes-unless-i-press-enter
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim iCell       As Range: Set iCell = Range("D23")

    If iCell.Value = "by Payor" Then
        Rows("29:78").Hidden = True
        Rows("80:135").Hidden = True
        Rows("137:192").Hidden = True
        Rows("194:249").Hidden = True
    ElseIf iCell.Value = "by Specialty" Then
        Rows("29:78").Hidden = False
        Rows("80:135").Hidden = False
        Rows("137:192").Hidden = False
        Rows("194:249").Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. I tried to put this code, but it didn't seem to give much effect. I still have to press the enter key on the changes cell for the code to run. Is there anything I can do about this? Thank you so much

Comment: Ni Luh Sila Dewi, Check again, I have updated the code above. It works for me, hides the rows when selecting a value (“D23”) by Payor and reveals them back when selecting a value (“D23”) by Specialty.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for the help. I've tried it and It actually works for the trigger cell that I put manually ("by Payor & by Specialty"). But unfortunately it doesn't work if the trigger cell is linked to a formula or another sheet, I still have to press on the enter button for the VBA to run

Comment: If the trigger cell is linked to a formula or another worksheet. 
You didn't say anything about this before. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Hi Mike so sorry for the very late reply, the code is functioning well and I am very helped. Thank your for the help Mike :)